How to find $L^p$ converging random variables $X_n$ where a specified non-Lipschitz continuous function of them, $g(X_n)$, does not converge in $L^p$?
Background: I am preparing for a probability theory exam, and am struggling with a particular type of problem. The questions involve showing that if $X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} X$, then it does not necessarily hold that for a given non-Lipschitz, unbounded continuous function $g$, that $g(X_n) \xrightarrow{L^p} g(X)$. The specific function $g$ changes every year, so I am looking for motivation on how to construct these counterexamples.
For completeness, $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^p$ (denoted: $X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} X$) if: $$\mathbb E [ | X_n - X \mid ^p] \rightarrow 0 $$
I know that this does not imply that $g(X_n)$ converges to $g(X)$ in $L^p$ in general unless $g$ is bounded or Lipschitz continuous (interestingly, Nate Eldredge informed me that there exist non-bounded, non-Lipschitz functions that still converge in this manner, although for the purposes of this question, those are not relevant).

How can I find examples of $L^p$ converging random variables, $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, where a specified non-Lipschitz continuous function of these random variables, $g(X_n)$, does not converge in $L^p$?
(i.e. where we know that $X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} X$ but $g(X_n) \xrightarrow{L^p} g(X)$ is not true)

Problem: The non-Lipchitz, unbounded functions that are given (to find counterexamples for) are continuous, so I don't need a strategy in complete generality. Some examples include taking $g(X_n)$ as $e^{X_n}$ and $X_n^2$ and showing that they do not converge in $L^p$ for all $X_n$ converging to $X$ in $L^p$.
At the moment, my strategy involves guessing sequences of random variables $X_n$ that I suspect converge in $L^p$ and then checking to see if these are suitable counterexamples. I would appreciate it if there is a more rigorous strategy I can employ.

Note: I am not interested in knowing answers to those particular examples above, I am more interested in understanding a more general approach (although it may be helpful to refer to those to explain the general approach).
Note$_2$: I do not necessarily expect there to be a completely generalizable approach to this type of question. Therefore, if the best that can be done is to give some strong intuition as to how to think about constructing these sequences of random variables, then that also constitutes an answer to my question.

Thank you in advance.

In order to have $X_n \overset{L^p}{\to} X$ implies $g(X_n) \overset{L^p}{\to} g(X)$ for all $X_n$, a necessary and sufficient condition on $g$ is that it should be continuous and have linear growth; i.e. $|g(t)| \le \alpha + \beta|t|$ for some constants $\alpha,\beta$, or equivalently $\limsup_{t \to \pm \infty} \left|\frac{g(t)}{t}\right| < \infty$.
In what follows, let us take $p=1$ for simplicity.  I leave it as an exercise to extend to general $1 \le p < \infty$.  I will also assume for simplicity that $g(0)=0$; again it is an exercise to remove this restriction.
It's clearly necessary that $g$ be continuous.  Now, if $g$ is continuous but does not have linear growth, then there exists a sequence $t_n$ with $|t_n| \to \infty$ such that $\left|\frac{g(t_n)}{t_n}\right| \to \infty$.  Since this implies $|g(t_n)| \to \infty$ as well, we can discard finitely many terms if needed so that $|g(t_n)| \ge 1$ for all $n$.  Define a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n = t_n$ with probability $\frac{1}{|g(t_n)|}$, and $X_n = 0$ otherwise.  Then $E|X_n| = \left|\frac{t_n}{g(t_n)}\right| \to 0$ by assumption, so $X_n \to 0$ in $L^1$.  On the other hand, we have
$$E|g(X_n)| = \frac{|g(t_n)|}{|g(t_n)|} + |g(0)| \left(1 - \frac{1}{|g(t_n)|} \right)\ge 1$$
so that $g(X_n)$ does not converge in $L^1$ to $g(0)=0$.

To see that the condition is sufficient, recall the Vitali convergence theorem: we have $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$ if and only if all of the following hold:

$X_n \to X$ in probability;

$\sup_n E|X_n| < \infty$;

$\displaystyle \lim_{P(A) \to 0} \sup_n E[|X_n| ; A] = 0.$


Suppose then that $g$ is continuous with linear growth, and that $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$.  We then have:

$g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in probability, by the continuous mapping theorem (this only requires $g$ to be continuous)

Let $M = \sup_n E|X_n| < \infty$.  For any $n$ we now have
$$E|g(X_n)| \le E\left[\alpha + \beta |X_n|\right] = \alpha + \beta E|X_n| \le \alpha + \beta M$$
and so $\sup_n E|g(X_n)| \le \alpha + \beta M < \infty$.

For any $A$ and any $n$, we have
$$E[|g(X_n)| ; A] \le E[\alpha + \beta |X_n| ; A] = \alpha P(A) + \beta E[|X_n| ; A]$$
so that
$$\sup_n E[|g(X_n)| ; A] \le \alpha P(A) + \beta \sup_n E[|X_n| ; A]$$
which goes to 0 as $P(A) \to 0$.


Hence $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in $L^1$.

Thank you for your answer. I think one thing that I am missing is how to explicitly know what $t_n$ is. I can see that it exists and its properties imply that we will not have convergence in $L^1$, but I am still unsure about how we explicitly characterise the sequence (for example taking $X^2$ or $e^X$ from the question, it is unclear that me how to construct the sequence as a function of $n$)

@FD_bfa: For nice functions like those, you could simply take $t_n = n$, or really any sequence with $t_n \to \infty$ would do.

And this answer, and your argument in the comment above, applies to an arbitrary probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ (I realized I did not specify in my question the space we are working on)?

@FD_bfa: Well, no, because an arbitrary probability space may not contain any events having the desired probabilities.  For instance if $\Omega$ consists of a finite number of atoms, you can show that all you need is for $g$ to be continuous.  So a more precise statement would be that the following are equivalent for any $1 \le p < \infty$:  (1) For every probability space $\Omega$ and every sequence of random variables $X_n, X$ on $\Omega$, $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$ implies $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in $L^p$.  (2) $g$ is continuous with linear growth.
